# Should I run 32 bit and 64 bit production applications on a 64 bit Debian server?

Tags: debian, 64-bit

I need to run 2 proprietary C++ applications, one is 64 bit and the other is 32 bit ,on a production Debian GNU/Linux server.

Both have a lot of dependencies for libraries provided by debian. Here are a few for example:

Application A (**64 bit**) depends on :

- mysql (64 bit)
- libssl (64 bit)
- Libboost (64 bit)
- ...

Application B (**32 bit**) depends on:

- libssl (32 bit)
- libboost (32 bit)
- ...

If I install debian lenny 64 bit, I will get a great OS for running application A on. But for application B, I will have to maintain (and update) the 32 bit libraries on my own, backporting each one to install itself to /usr/lib32.

Is there another way to go about this problem that I haven’t thought of? Or is this a bad idea which should not be used on a production server?

Comment: Must it be on Debian? There are other distros that have mostly solved this.

Comment: Yes, it must be Debian. Although not necessarily Lenny, squeeze is an option too.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to build a complete 32 bit install to be run as a chroot environment, debian has good tools for this I would look at debootstrap for example

```
debootstrap --arch i386 gutsy /mnt/32bit_install http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
```

See [Installing Debian GNU/Linux from a Unix/Linux System](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en)

Comment: I'm aware of the chroot option. However, when thinking of running a production server, with a production application inside a chroot, it just feels wrong. You basically still end up managing 2 OSes in terms of security updates. Not to mention taking care of startup issues (who will start the application service from the chroot?), having 2 sets of /var/log/*. It just complicates things in a way I would rather not have complicated on a production server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal situation. Debian has some great howtos related to this problem. See [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/534). Chrooting the 32bit app will give you a clean 32bit environment to play with and maintain properly.